# Как сделать систему сессий в Aiogram боте?

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть Aiogram бот, и я хочу сделать в нем систему сессий. Вкратце - когда человек пользуется ботом, он нажимает на кнопки и использует команды. В таком случае, активируется сессия, которая живет полчаса.

Главная проблема этой идеи, что я не знаю как реализовать подобное со стороны кода. Нельзя сделать старт сессии с старт-хендлера, ибо пользоваться ботом можно не сразу нажав на кнопку старт.

Есть ли у вас идеи, как сделать "теневой" message/query хэндлер, который будет отслеживать абсолютно все действия пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В aiogram существуют [миддлвари](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/middlewares.html), которые срабатывают на какое-то событие(`message`, `callback_query` и т.п.).

Они делятся на 2 типа, Внешние и Внутренние. В нашем случае можно использовать внешние миддлвари.

Ниже код, написанный на aiogram v3.1.1:

```py
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, Dict
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware

# Пишем миддлварь
class TestMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def __call__(self, handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]], event: TelegramObject, data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
        # Здесь записываем нужные нам обработчики
        return await handler(event,data) # возвращаем в случае, если хотим чтобы работал дальнейший код.
```

```py
from aiogram import Dispatcher

dp = Dispatcher() # объявляем диспетчер
dp.message.outer_middleware(TestMiddleware()) # Объявляем для всех хэндлеров message внешний миддлварь
```

Таким образом можно внутри миддлвари записывать/читать нужные нам данные, например в базе данных время сессии.

Comment: Спасибо! Я пользовался мидлварями, но видимо где-то отступился, раз у меня не вышло самостоятельно